# useUnsafeHeaderParsing in Windows Service Application

Tags: c#

I have a VS2005 windows service where I have the need to use 'useUnsafeHeaderParsing' as per documentation from MSDN.

As this is a library used within my windows service, I do not have a web.config to add httpwebrequest element and set useUnsafeHeaderParsing to true.

How would I go about achieving this in code. I tried [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/ff098248-551c-4da9-8ba5-358a9f8ccc57/) and [this](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Setting_unsafeheaderparsing) but that was a no go.

Answer (score 5):

You can enable unsafeHeaderParsing programmatically if you wish - here's a function I included in [Quick and Dirty Feed Parser](http://qdfeed.codeplex.com/) for turning that on - it's similar to some of the ones you linked to in your question:

```
private static bool SetUseUnsafeHeaderParsing(bool b)
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection));
        if (a == null) return false;

        Type t = a.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal");
        if (t == null) return false;

        object o = t.InvokeMember("Section",
            BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, null, new object[] { });
        if (o == null) return false;

        FieldInfo f = t.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (f == null) return false;

        f.SetValue(o, b);

        return true;
    }
```

I've used that in production code and it works fine, regardless of what environment you're deployed in - as long as the System.Net.Configuration namespace is accessible via some assembly in the GAC you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the trouble is.

You don't use a web.config with a windows service, you use App.config (this gets moved into the deployment directory when you compile and renamed to .config

I have used this setting in my App.Config for windows forms applications, web applications and many windows services without difficulty.